# Can i list unmounted drives without fdisk or lsblk?

Tags: mount, fdisk, router, external-hdd, lsblk

I have an Inteno dg200 Router running some Iopsys linux version (kernel 3.14 or so, I believe)

I've had some trouble getting a fileshare running using the USB ports and my external harddrive. The system supports it. But no matter what I put in, it does not automatically mount it. So today I decided to ssh into the system as root rather than use my webbased control panel.

To my surprise the system does not support the usual ways of finding information on the connected, unmounted drives. Allow me to elaborate:

```
# fdisk -l
-ash: fdisk: not found
```

Very well, lets try something else then:

```
# lsblk
-ash: lsblk: not found
```

And so I begin running into trouble. From what I have been able to learn online, when people have this problem it's usually because `fdisk` lies in */sbin*, and that is not in their path as they are not root. Well, I am root here, but to be certain I checked both */sbin* and */usr/sbin*, but to no avail. Neither directory contained anything called `fdisk` or `lsblk`, nor does the `find` command locate anything called `fdisk`.

Is there another way to find out what exactly to mount from CLI or can I, perhaps install `fdisk` on the router?

Comment: what does dmesg say?

Comment: Well quite a lot. Do you want me to post it all, or should i run it with a specific argument or something?

Comment: the last few lines, or taking out and putting in the external drive should be of interest for you

Comment: These are the ones that seem to concern USB:

`[319198.887000] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd
[319214.101000] usb 1-1: can't set config #1, error -145
`

Comment: Both `lsblk` and `fdisk` come from `util-linux` package, so it seem you don't have it installed (but `mount` comes from it also, so it looks strange). Perhaps you have parted: `parted -l`?

Comment: Does `busybox fdisk -l` work?

Comment: `parted` does not work, it's the same as the others.

`busybox fdisk -l`gives me `fdisk: applet not found`

Answer (score 4):

When the kernel looks for possible devices it looks at

```
cat /proc/partitions
```

Sample output:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  488386584 sda
   8        1  472382464 sda1
   8        2          1 sda2
   8        5   16001024 sda5
  11        0    1048575 sr0
```

The already mounted devices can nab found with

```
mount | grep ^/
```

Sample output:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext3 (rw,noatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
```

If you don't have the `mount` command then

```
cat /etc/mtab
```

or

```
cat /proc/mounts
```

Comment: `cat /proc/partitions` gives me

`major minor  #blocks  name

  31        0       5120 mtdblock0
  31        1       5120 mtdblock1
  31        2        384 mtdblock2
  31        3        128 mtdblock3
  31        4     119296 mtdblock4
  31        5      52224 mtdblock5
  31        6      67072 mtdblock6
  31        7      55056 mtdblock7
  31        8      55056 mtdblock8
`

I'm not sure how that is useful though.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> cat /proc/partitions gives me
>
> ```
> major minor #blocks name 
> 31 0 5120 mtdblock0 
> 31 1 5120 mtdblock1 
> 31 2 384 mtdblock2 
> 31 3 128 mtdblock3 
> 31 4 119296 mtdblock4 
> 31 5 52224 mtdblock5 
> 31 6 67072 mtdblock6 
> 31 7 55056 mtdblock7 
> 31 8 55056 mtdblock8
> ```
>
> I'm not sure how that is useful though.

That indicates the router is using a Memory Technology Device as its system-disk-equivalent - and if the USB HDD is currently plugged in, then the USB storage driver is probably not even loaded.

You would need to do something like `modprobe usb-storage` first. If that is successful, then the partitions of the USB HDD should get added to the list in `/proc/partitions`.